# Return promise in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, return

i try to return data in node.js from a APIs , but I'm having problems, because I need an asynchronous function, I couldn't understand for sure the correct use of the promise, I've tried everything and I couldn't put the result in the return, only in the console.log, somebody help me?

```
const express = require('express')
const MFA = require('mangadex-full-api')

module.exports = {
    async indexManga(req, res) {
         
        const mangalist = MFA.login('DarksGol', 'R@ul1605', './md_cache/').then(async () => {

            manga = []
                await MFA.Manga.search('Kiss').then(results => {
                results.forEach((elem, i) => {   
                    let obj = {}
                    obj.status = elem.status
                    obj.title = elem.title
                    
                    manga.push(obj)
                })
            }).catch(console.error)

            return manga

        }).catch(console.error) 

        console.log(await mangalist)
        return mangalist
    }
}
```

no error occurred, only infinite loading on request

```
const express = require('express')
const routes = express.Router()

const searchManga = require('../src/controllers/searchManga')

routes.get('/searchManga', searchManga.indexManga)

module.exports = routes
```

Comment: Share the require file code of this exports, uses of this export funtion

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling `indexManga`, please?

Comment: Btw, I really hope that `R@ul1605` is not your real password. If it was, you need to change it immediately.

Comment: it's not my password!

I believe the problem is not in my index call, as I have already made another callback to test my route and it works perfectly,

If the problem isn't asynchronous and waits from the functions, where the return is a promise, so the return tries to send something before it's actually done!

But I have no idea how to solve this!

Comment: @Raul Not sure who *DarksGol* is, but his password does work. Where did you get this code from? Report the incident to the author.

Comment: @Raul What do you mean by "*I have already made another callback to test my route*"? Please just [edit] your question to include the code where you call `indexManga` and "*send something*".

Comment: indexManga it's just the name of the route, I'm almost 100% sure that the problem isn't there, I've attached the code where I configure that my IndexManga is the function I want to run.

Comment: This password is a test from this API, I don't use it for anything else, so it's no problem for it to be there, you can even use it to test this API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `indexManga` is an endpoint. Each endpoint function must end the request-response cycle by sending a response ( res.send(), res.json(), res.end(), etc). If `indexManga` s an endpoint, the solution would be:

```
...

//return mangalist
res.send(mangalist)
```

or

```
//return mangalist
res.json({ status: "success", message: "logged in successfully" })
```

If it is a meddleware:

```
async indexManga(req, res, next) {
  ...
  //return mangalist
  return next()
}
```

EDIT: you are using `async/await` with `.then()` improperly in some places.
Try this way:

```
module.exports = {
    indexManga(req, res) {
        MFA.login('DarksGol', 'R@ul1605', './md_cache/').then(() => {

            manga = []
            MFA.Manga.search('Kiss').then(results => {
                results.forEach((elem, i) => {   
                    let obj = {}
                    obj.status = elem.status
                    obj.title = elem.title
                    
                    manga.push(obj)
                })
                
                res.json({ status: "success", data: manga })
                
            }).catch((err) => {
               res.json({ status: "fail", error: err })
            })
            

        }).catch((err) => {
           res.json({ status: "fail", error: err })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ABDULLOKH, you're right, I ended up forgetting to add the endpoint, but it didn't work, as the variable is trying to be sent before it's ready, so that wasn't the problem, but in fact, I needed to add res.json in my code , thanks!

Comment: Thanks, ABDULLOKH, your method is perfect, problem solved :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this would cause "*infinite loading on request*", but you could greatly simplify the code to just

```
const express = require('express');
const MFA = require('mangadex-full-api');

module.exports = {
    async indexManga(req, res) {
        await MFA.login('DarksGol', 'R@ul1605', './md_cache/')
        const mangaList = [];
        const results = await MFA.Manga.search('Kiss');
        results.forEach(elem => {   
            mangaList.push({
                status: elem.status,
                title: elem.title,
            });
        });
        return mangalist;
    },
};
```

Comment: Thanks Bergi, I don't understand what's causing the infinite loading either, but thanks for improving my code <3